# Convert date into dd-mm-yy format and select last 12 dates from a picked value in SQL 2008

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008, datetime

I have a table with a column 'Required date'. I need to convert the date format into dd-mm-yy format. I am able to do that using the following code -

```
Select Convert(VARCHAR(8),[RecordDate], 3) AS [DD/MM/YY]
From [resolveConfig].dbo.myTable
```

Now, when a date is picked, I would like to select the last 12 days data from the table from the 'picked date'.

How can I do that?
It is already converting the date to string format so i guess dateadd() would not work?

I am using sql 2008.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will only take the last 12 dates

`SELECT TOP 12 CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),[RecordDate], 3) AS [DD/MM/YY] FROM [resolveConfig].dbo.myTable ORDER BY [DD/MM/YY] DESC`

**Update 1 :**

With the extra information it seems you are looking for the following :

`SELECT Convert(VARCHAR(8),[RecordDate], 3) AS [DD/MM/YY] FROM [resolveConfig].dbo.myTable  WHERE [DD/MM/YY] >= DATEADD('11-10-2015', -12) AND [DD/MM/YY] <= '11-10-2015'`

Ofcourse instead of using the string date that i used here you can use a variable.
Documentation on the dateadd function : 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_adddate

Comment: Thanks for answering Mythje.
But probably my question framing was wrong. I wanted to select the last 12 dates from any date. (dynamic)            
ie - If i select 25-07-2014, It should display the data for 12 days before 25-07-2014.